# How to animate a custom view to a custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, koloda

I'm building a flashcard-like app, and I'm using a library KolodaView: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

I have this extension which returns a `UIView` as the front of a flashcard:

```
extension StudyViewController: KolodaViewDataSource {

func kolodaNumberOfCards(koloda:KolodaView) -> UInt {
    return UInt(memories.count)
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {
    return UIImageView(image: memories[Int(index)].frontImage)
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardOverlayAtIndex index: UInt) -> OverlayView? {

    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OverlayView",owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? OverlayView
}
}
```

And I want to be able to transform the from view to the back view with a tap:

```
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSelectCardAtIndex index: UInt) {

    let frontView: UIView = koloda as KolodaView
    let backView: UIView = UIImageView(image: memories[Int(index)].backImage)

    if showingFront == true {
        UIView.transitionFromView(frontView, toView: backView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIView.transitionFromView(backView, toView: frontView, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)
        showingFront = false
    }
}
```

The transition was successful but after it finishes, the flashcard will turn from a `KolodaView` to a giant `UIView`

How do I transform a `KolodaView` to anther `KolodaView`?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used `KolodaView` so my answers are more generic to the problem at hand.

**Two approaches**

**a. Variant of your current approach (Hackish way)**

As the library do not expose the reference to the shown imageView, you will first need to maintain your internal set of imageView for later use.

```
private var myImageViews: [Int: UIImageView] = [:]
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: memories[Int(index)].frontImage)
    myImageViews[Int(index)] = imageView
    return imageView
}
```

Animate view using your current approach and update the final state of the original image using the completion block.

```
UIView.transitionFromView(frontView,
                          toView: backView,
                          duration: duration,
                          options: [.TransitionCrossDissolve, .ShowHideTransitionViews],
                          completion: { [weak self] (finished: Bool) in
        let imageView = myImageViews[Int(index)]
        imageView.image = memories[Int(index)].frontImage
        frontView.hidden = false
        backView.hidden = true
        backView.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

**b. Return a custom view in the datasource method, and toggle its internal state in didSelectCardAtIndex**

```
private var myCustomViews: [Int: MyCustomView] = [:]
func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {
    let customView = MyCustomView(frontImage: memories[Int(index)].frontImage, 
                                  backImage: memories[Int(index)].backImage)
    myCustomViews[Int(index)] = customView
    return customView
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSelectCardAtIndex index: UInt) {
    let customView = myCustomViews[Int(index)]
    customView.toggleFrontBackState()
}
```

In this case, the implementation for `toggleFrontBackState` will contain the code of your initial implementation (customView.showingFront, transitionFromView). Let me know if you need more clarification.

**EDIT**

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    private(set) lazy var frontView: UIImageView = self.makeFrontView()
    private(set) lazy var backView: UIImageView = self.makeBackView()
    var showingFront: Bool = false

    init(frontImage: UIImage?, backImage: UIImage?){
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        frontView.image = frontImage
        backView.image = backImage
        backView.hidden = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func toggleFrontBackState() {
        if showingFront {
            UIView.transitionFromView(frontView, toView: backView, duration: 1, 
                                      options: [.TransitionCrossDissolve, .ShowHideTransitionViews], completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIView.transitionFromView(backView, toView: frontView, duration: 1, 
                                      options: [.TransitionCrossDissolve, .ShowHideTransitionViews] , completion: nil)
        }
        showingFront = !showingFront
    }

    func makeFrontView() -> UIImageView {
        return UIImageView()
    }

    func makeBackView() -> UIImageView {
        return UIImageView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on the b methods? How do you implement `MyCustomView` class and `toggleFrontBackState()` method?

Comment: It seems like the `kolodaviewDatasource` only accepts a single `UIImageView` as the return value, whenever I try to pass 2 `UIImageView`, it becomes blank

Comment: You should return MyCustomView (not two ImageView). See code in approach B

Comment: What are the `makeFront/BackView` methods?

Comment: Just initialise a UIImageView in those function. Updated code section above

Comment: Then Xcode sends an error say: use of self in property access `front/backView` before super.init() initialises

Comment: There's no super.init method provided in the class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120957/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-bright-future).